# Найдите все пары дружественных чисел в промежутке от 1 до 1000. На PHP

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, дружественная-функция

я написал код. но он очень тормозит

```
    function div($n){
    $res = [];
    for($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++){
        if($n % $i === 0){
            $res[] += $i;
        }
        }
        return $res;
}
    function friendlyNum($min, $max){
    $data = [];
    for ($n = $min; $n <= $max; ++$n)  { 
    $data[$n] = array_sum(div($n)); 
     } 
     foreach ($data as $key => $el)  { 
        if ($el < $key && $key == $data[$el]){
             echo $el, ' ', $key, "\n";
            } 
        } 
   }
   friendlyNum(1, 10000);
```

Можете написать более легкую версию кода? Если можно с комментариями.

Comment: то есть вы считаете, что не надо в задаче словами написать, что такое дружественные числа?

Comment: Если вы не знаете что такое Дружественные числа, вряд ли вы мне сможете помочь. Ибо это математика. Ну а если интересно, то скопировать и вставить в гугл

Comment: бгг, ок. простите что вмешался.

Answer (score 1):

Крутить 10к раз цикл по 10к совсем не нужно, если знать немного математики :)

```php
<?php
function getOwnDivisorsSumm( $n ) {
    $result = 0;
    if( $n > 1 ) {
        $result = 1; 
        $sqrt = sqrt( $n );
        for ( $i = 2; $i < $sqrt; $i++ ) {
            if ( $n % $i == 0 ) {
                $result += $i + $n / $i;
            }
        }
        if ( floor( $sqrt ) == $sqrt ) {
            $result += $sqrt;
         }
    }
    return $result;
}   

$n = 10000;

echo "Пары \"дружественных чисел\"\nв диапазоне от 1 до ".$n.":\n"; 
for( $z = 1; $z < $n; $z++)
{
    $currDivs = getOwnDivisorsSumm($z);
    $rsltDivs = getOwnDivisorsSumm($currDivs);
    
    if ( $z == $rsltDivs && $currDivs != $rsltDivs ) {
        echo $z." и ".$currDivs."\n";
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Пары "дружественных чисел"
 в диапазоне от 1 до 10000: 
220 и 284
284 и 220
1184 и 1210
1210 и 1184
2620 и 2924
2924 и 2620
5020 и 5564
5564 и 5020
6232 и 6368
6368 и 6232
```

P.S Можно конечно результаты засунуть в массив и проверять нет ли в нем уже повторяющихся результатов, а-ля "220 и 284" и "284 и 220", но мне было лень :)

Comment: Спасибо конечно. Что то подобное видел. Но я не понимаю как это работает. Может прокомментируешь строки кода? Либо направь меня на материал который нужно выучить, что бы я понял. С математикой плохо. Но готов учиться

Comment: Там математика первых классов - что там может быть непонятного? :)

Comment: Седьмой или восьмой класс. Я не любил тогда учиться ...

Comment: Тогда учитесь сейчас - возьмите код и разберите его по-строчно, что происходит на каждой строке - придет понимание и математики.

Comment: как я разберу его, если я не знаю базы. направь меня какой раздел математики надо выучить. мне уже 50 лет. много позабыл